# Webview back button causing error

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Eclipse is showing a `main is not a field or cannot be resolved` error in the `setContentView(R.layout.main);` line.  I have tried to add an import, `import android.R;`, but all it does is cause more errors.  The errors how ever seem to surround lines that contain "R" in them.  Any suggestions?

Here's my xml file

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

   <TextView
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:text="This is the demo of WebView Client"
       android:textSize="20sp"
       android:gravity="center_horizontal">       
   </TextView>

    <ProgressBar
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="center"
       android:id="@+id/progressBar1"/>      

   <WebView
       android:id="@+id/webview01"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_weight="1">
   </WebView>



</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the activity file

```
   package com.example.xxx;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;



public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    WebView web;
    ProgressBar progressBar;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview01);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

        web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        web.loadUrl("http://www.technotalkative.com");
    }

    public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
    {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }


    @Override 
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && web.canGoBack()) {
            web.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

}
```

Comment: Hope you've already tried cleaning the project and have checked for the existence of the xml file in your layout folder. It not suggested to include .R by yourself. Let it automatically generate.

Answer (score 1):

You should not `import android.R`, but `import you.package.name.R` instead, android since you use `R.layout.main`, make sure you layout file called **main.xml** under res/layout.

Comment: i tried adding that and it worked but any suggestions as to why my progress bar just displays the progress bar but doesnt go to the webpage? @A.man @EricHua23?

Comment: Have you add Internet Permission in you AndroidManifest.xml     `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Comment: yeah i have that. @EricHua23